# Where is the permission to access pricesets?

Tags: permissions, price-sets, user, roles, access

I remember there was a permission to access price sets via drupal roles. But in the latest version that permission seems missing. Can anyone help please how can I give permission to update price set to a user with a different role than admin?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user can manage price sets if they have Access CiviEvent and Edit all events (actually they can access it with just Access CiviEvent with the URL or a manually added menu item, but in order for it to appear in the menu by default they also need Edit all events). It appears in the Events menu, but it allows access to price sets of all kinds, not just for events.